# Focus an NSSearchField on menu open

Tags: macos, cocoa

The view of the first item in a menu is an `NSSearchField`. How to set focus on that search field as soon as the menu is open? (Think the search field in the "Help" menu in every Mac app.)

I've tried this in the menu's delegate:

```
func menuWillOpen(menu: NSMenu) {
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow?.makeFirstResponder(searchField)
}
```

It doesn't work. But that makes sense, as this method is called `menuWillOpen` not `menuDidOpen`.

Comment: I only recently learned about NSMenuItems-- but here's my thought: In the example of the mainmenu, it is an NSMenu with NSMenuItems (e.g help), and these NSMenuItem contain another submenu(`NSMenu`).  You could try to add an action to the 'help' NSMenuItem (because there is currently no action, it just opens a submenu)-- then for that action make it set the search field as the first responder

Comment: Target-action will be triggered only if you click on the menu item. What I mean is that, the search field should get focus once the menu is open, without clicking on or hovering over the search field. Just click the "Help" menu in your web browser and you will know what I mean.

Comment: Right-- I got you; but the 'Help' is an NSMenuItem, is what I'm saying.

Your app's mainmenu is an NSMenu, which contains NSMenuItems (File, Edit, View, Help, etc). These NSMenuItems contain an NSMenu as a submenu, so now when you click on them they open the submenu.  But you should still be able to set an action on click for the NSMenuItems that will get called alongside of opening the submenu

Comment: I tried your approach. The action isn't triggered at all for the top level `NSMenuItem`s

Comment: Damn.  Sorry that was the best Idea I could come up for you.  Apple has to do it somehow right??

Comment: Have you had a look here?: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SearchFields/Articles/MenuTemplate.html and here http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/195835-set-focus-on-nsview-in-an-nsmenuitem.html

Comment: I did read the post on cocoabuilder. But looks like the OP didn't solve his question either. I've tried using a timer to make the search field the first responder - it doesn't work.